# Can't select/copy close reason text in Chrome?

Tags: bug, user-interface

Often times, if I vote to close a question, I'll copy the close reason text and edit it to form a comment explaining the problem with the question. However, I find some slightly problematic behavior today in Chrome on Ubuntu:  When I select the close reason text, the radio button it automatically selected, and on some platforms, this deselects the text selection.

Behavior on various platforms:

- Google Chrome on Ubuntu: the automatic radio button is selected and the text gets de-selected.

  - *I've found that if I hold the left-mouse button down and right-click before releasing the left-mouse button, the radio button doesn't get automatically selected, and I don't lose my text selection.  Presumably some on release notification isn't getting handled in the same way?  I don't think this is a great workaround, though…*
- Internet Explorer 11 on Windows: the radio button is selected, but the text selection remains.
- Firefox on Windows & Ubuntu: the radio button is *not* automatically selected, and the text selection remains.

Was there some recent change?  Was it intentional?

Comment: This might be general to the whole network.  If that's the case, and this belongs on meta.SE, I'm happy to delete this and take it over there, or it could be migrated.

Comment: If you encountered it on SO it's perfectly fine to post about it here

Comment: Does not happen to me, can you tell more about when it happens (maybe its specific to a question, or to one level of the close reasons)? Also have you tried it with a different browser, or maybe with browser addons disabled (including user scripts)? I found that there can be quite some bad interactions.

Comment: Browser/OS may have some bearing here. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I've added more information.  Amazing how I so often ask on SO questions for more details, I can still so quickly forget to provide them when I'm reporting a problem.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I see now what you mean, I can confirm this on chrome 34.0.1847.92 on linux (openSUSE 13.1). Additionally for me, the whole `div` where the radio button resides in becomes gray. I further noticed that on firefox, when selecting the radio button appears in a dimmed selected way. I can imagine some javascript/css/whatever causing this and would guess it has to do with the structure that is responsible for making it possible to select the radio button by clicking on the text.

Comment: @juergend I rolled back the tag edit:  This is about a (possible) glitch in the UI, so I think that the [tag:user-interface] is appropriate, and while it's about the close reasons part of the interface, it's not really about the close reasons themselves, so I'm not confident that [tag:close-reasons] is.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Your question is the only one tagged with this tag. It is a bad tag because almost all of the bugs have in a way something to do with the UI. You should choose a more specific tag. If you remove it then the tag itself will be removed since no other questions are attachted to it.

Comment: @juergend Oh;  I didn't notice that no questions have it yet.  Why does it already have a tag description?  I didn't type it in freehand;  it was one of the autocomplete options.  Is this a biproduct of the meta-split?

Comment: 2 other questions used the tag and I removed it from them too.

Comment: @juergend Well, if you keep doing that, you'll ensure that "[the] question is the only one tagged with this tag" each time one appears. :)

Comment: Hopefully soon no questions are tagged with that tag any more. :)

Comment: Well, I think this is more a browser bad behavior than bug on SE side. Text selection should not trigger the click event of the element.